# How do I solve this Java recursion without an else case?

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion, case, radix

```
public void doSomething(int n){
     if (n > 0){
          doSomething(n-1);
          System.out.print(n);
          doSomething(n-1);
     }
}
```

If I write: doSomething(3), the terminal prints 1213121, but I am not able to follow the recursive process because there is only a base case and no else case. What does the function do if n==0 ? And how does that proceed the recursive step?

Comment: If `n <= 0` the method *returns*, pure and simple.

Comment: The base case is n==0 and the recursive case is n>1. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. 
When n==0 it does nothing, it returns. What do you want it to do when n==0?

also you calling the doSomething() twice in the same loop is not wrong, but seems weird.

Comment: Try debugging step by step and following the path of execution. I'd imagine it will become clear to you.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion doesn't necessary to have `base` case. It only requires 2 things:

1. a point the program can terminate (`i == 0` in this case)
2. each recursive call runs in a direction approaching that point (`doSomething(n - 1)` in this case instead of `doSomething(n + 1)`)

If you prefer to think in a `base` case way, your code is exactly the same as:

```
public void doSomething(int n){
     if (n <= 0) {
         return;
     }

     doSomething(n-1);
     System.out.print(n);
     doSomething(n-1);
}
```

In case you're interested, your code logic resembles the recursive version of `inorder traversal` of binary tree. You may refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order for some more insights.

Answer (score 0):

> What does the function do if n==0 ?

Absolutely nothing.

> And how does that proceed the recursive step?

It doesn't proceed.

And it *shouldn't* proceed.  When `n <= 0` the code should not recurse any further.

Someone advised you to run the code using a debugger to help you *visualize* what is going on.  That should help you with this conceptual problem too:

> I am not able to follow the recursive process because there is only a base case and no `else` case.

You have misunderstood the basics of recursion.  It does not require an `else` case.  What is *actually* requires is a way to stop recursing.  An `else` case is one possibility, but there are a variety of others.

Or ... to bring it back to your example ... your code is equivalent to this:

```
public void doSomething(int n){
     if (n > 0){
          doSomething(n-1);
          System.out.print(n);
          doSomething(n-1);
     } else {
          // this is a comment
     }
}
```

Now there is an `else` case ... which is an empty block.  Or you could put a redundant `return` statement into the block.  (I assume that you can figure out *why* it is redundant!)

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is a good example for recursion.
It generates all combinations with `0` and `1` and length `5` recursive,  a pattern results :

Result :

```
00000
00001
00010
00011
00100
00101
00110
00111
01000
01001
01010
01011
01100
01101
01110
01111
10000
10001
10010
10011
10100
10101
10110
10111
11000
11001
11010
11011
11100
11101
11110
11111
```

Code :

```
class Stringhelper {
    public Stringhelper() {
    }
    public String getstring(String string,int beginning,int ending) {
         if (string.length() != 0) {
         String newstring="";
         for (int iter=Math.abs(beginning); iter < ending && iter < string.length(); iter=iter+1) {
              newstring=newstring+Character.toString(string.charAt(iter));
         }
         return newstring;
         }
         else {
         return "";
         }
    }
}



public class Counter {
     public String abil=""; //Possible Combinations
     public int iter=0;
     public Stringhelper shelper=new Stringhelper();
     public void loop(int iter) {
         for (int i=0; i < 2; i++) {
              abil=shelper.getstring(abil,0,iter); //Crop everything until this char, if string was 010, for and iter is 2 : 01+result of this loop
              abil=abil+Integer.toString(i);
              if (iter==4) { //0,1,2,3,4=Length 5
                  System.out.println(abil);
              }
              else {
                  loop(iter+1);
              }
         }
     }
     public Counter() {
         loop(iter);
     }
     public static void main(String args[]){
         new Counter();
     }
}
```

It works like that :

For example with length 2*2=4 combinations.

Is :

```
00
01
10
11
```

But how does it produce that ?

It works so :

First call : loop(0) is executed.

The loop has actually `i=0`. It writes it down. The string is `"0"`. Now it launches `loop(1)`. This function has `i=0` at first, adds it, now the string is `"00"`, it notices that its already the second loop, and so it does print it but doesnt launch the function again. `"00"` is printed out. Now the loop goes further.`i=1`. First it tries to cut all chars until now, so out of `"00"`, there only stays the first zero, so its `"0"`. Now `"1"` is appended, String is `"01"`. It notices that its already the second loop, and so it does print it but doesnt launch the function again. `"01"` is printed. This function has continued and so it goes back to the first function. The loop there now runs further, it tries to cut all chars until now, so now we have a cleared string `""`. It launches `loop(1)` .This function has `i=0` at first, adds it to the string, now the string is `"10"`, it notices that its already the second loop, and so it does print it but doesnt launch the function again. `"10"` is printed out. Now the loop goes further. `i=1`. First it tries to cut all chars until now, so out of `"10"`, there only stays the first char, so its `"1"`. Now `"1"` is appended, String is `"11"`. It notices that its already the second loop, and so it does print it but doesnt launch the function again. `"11"` is printed. No process is running anymore.